# Optimizing Concave function

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I would like to solve the below problem:
$min_C \sum_i \phi(c_i)$ s.t $\sum_i c_i=1 $ and $c_i\geq 0$  where $i=1 \cdots k$ and $C = [c_i]$.
Here $\phi(x)$ is concave function. for example $\phi(x) = 2x - x^2$.

Given any valid initial point, i know the solution would be $[0\  0\  0 \cdots 1]$. Can anyone guide me to derive a gradient descent based algorithm to achieve this solution.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com seems more appropriate for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the Hastie, Tibshirani book: Elements of Statistical Learning. It's free! This sounds very much like a maximum entropy neural net. The constraints are similar to that of a log linear model, suggesting the use of Lagrange multipliers for an analytic solution. But you also seem interested in a more general activation function than the softmax (logistic). You can reference project pursuit regression which estimates a spline-based activation function.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure. It is a concave function and you want minimize it (not maximize). First of all, there is a chance that you fall into local mimina b.c you are mimizing a concave function. 
Anyway, one of the approach is to use spectral gradient projection(SPG). Why? because you have a feasible set (ie.  c_i >= 0   \sum c_i = 1) and you need to project your gradient step on the feasible set to stay feasible (ie inside of the set). If you are familiar with R, there is a nice package which does that for you. for SPG you need to provide gradient of your cost function and a projection function that map any to your feasible set. Computing gradient must be easy in your case. To find out how to write a projection algorithm (specifically for your feasible set) check out:

http://www.athenasc.com/nonlinbook.html

and look for projection on simplex (this is what your feasible set is called)